# Strangely, can't convert simple php soap call into python

Tags: php, python, soap

This seemed easy at first sight but I can't get it to work at all

We are moving a website from wordpress to django. I have to use the [payline](http://www.payline.com/) api to make the website accept online payments. I know there are other solutions but this is a client requirement.

In their [php library](https://support.payline.com/hc/fr/article_attachments/200779053/payline_PHP_v4.38.zip) (works fine) :

```php
$client = new SoapClient('/.../spec.wsdl', ['login' => 'xxx', 'password' => 'yyy']);
$client->__setLocation("https://homologation.payline.com/V4/services/WebPaymentAPI");
$response = $client->doWebPayment($WSRequest);
```

In Python, I tried this :

```python
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(url='https://homologation.payline.com/V4/services/WebPaymentAPI', headers={'login': 'xxx', 'password': 'yyy'})
request = client.factory.create('doWebPaymentRequest')
# filling up request parameters
result = client.service.doWebPayment(request)
```

But I get a http 401 : unauthorized access.

I have tried desperately a couple of things in the last 3 hours but none worked : I tried to use pysimplesoap, tried to use a custom transport object, tried to do ?wsdl in the client url (which worked a little) and setting the login/password via set_options

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suds documentation is lacking so here is something that worked, at least for the server setup I had to work with (unknown to me)

```
client = Client(url='file://path/to/wsdl')
client.set_options(param1="xxx", param2="yyy", ...)
```

in my case, `param1` was "username", `param2` was "password" etc, but these are specific to the  server's authentication scheme